# Pass file to import as a parameter in a python function

Tags: python, function, python-import, python-module

I am creating a functional "component" which has the following structure right now:

```py
from config_file import *
def FunctionalComponent():
  foo(a_from_config)
  bar(b_from_config)
  ...
```

but want to convert it into something like

```py
def functional_component(module_file):
  <do something with `module_file` which imports all the variables>
  foo(a_from_config)
  bar(b_from_config)
  ...
```

which can be called by the end user as

```py
functional_component(module_file = "path_to_config_file.py")
```

but am not able to find a good way to do so.
I tried using

```
def FunctionalComponent(module_file):
    from module_file import a_from_config
    print(a_from_config)
```

and calling it as (i wasn't sure how to pass the string (path to file) and import it, so tried passing the imported module itself. For the final function, passing a path(string) as a parameter is needed)

```
import module_file
FunctionalComponent(module_file)
```

but that gave `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_file'`

Any advice would be highly appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)

Comment: @Barmar Oh my god thank you very much, this was the exact thing needed! Could you maybe add it as an answer and I can accept it? Or should I write one with what I did.